# How to prevent Symfony 2 from setting global variables in templates?

Tags: php, symfony

How to tell Symfony2 not to set global variables (like `app`) in templates? I'd like to set my own `app` variable but it has `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\GlobalVariables Object` type event if I overwrite it in my controller.

Comment: Can't you just use your own variable for your app object, like `myapp` instead of `app`?  By changing the built-in behaviour of the framework, your code will become very unportable.

Comment: Can't you use something like `my_app` instead of `app`? I'm not sure about this but there's a chance some internals of Symfony might depend on this variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is such possibility (basically never did it cause `app` var can be handy ;) )

`app` global is added in constructor of `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine` (for twig) and in constructor of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\PhpEngine` (for php)

but when you do not pass `GlobalVariables` to constructor (can be null) it will not set `app` variable. So you can overwrite `templating` service like that:

```
    <service id="templating" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Templating\TwigEngine">
        <argument type="service" id="twig" />
        <argument type="service" id="templating.name_parser" />
        <argument type="service" id="templating.locator" /> 
    </service>
```

and php file:

```
<?php 

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Templating;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine as BaseEngine;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocatorInterface;

class TwigEngine extends BaseEngine
{
    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $environment, TemplateNameParserInterface $parser, FileLocatorInterface $locator)
    { 
        parent::__construct($environment, $parser, $locator);
    } 
}
```

You should be aware that you can implement own globals without that as well... just define own `templating.globals` service which will replace original one.